# Jquery resizing of 4 columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following [jsfiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/cashman04/3Xu8p/1/embedded/result/), which is using this JS:

```
$(".blah").on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('col-md-9');
    $(this).toggleClass('col-md-3 col-md-9');   
    $('.blah').not(this).toggleClass('col-md-3 col-md-1');
});
```

That does what I need, which is: using bootstrap, have 4 columns that always add up to their "12".  Currently, if I click a column, it resizes itself to be bigger, and changes the others to be smaller.  But I can't get it to work, so that if one column is set to `col-md-9`, and I click another column, it should set itself to larger, and shrink the others.  On my test page this works just fine so that the columns are side by side. No clue why my jsfiddle doesn't work the same, but it should still get my point across.  I just want whatever column I click on, to be larger than the others. Unless I click on the larger column, which would then set them all back to equal sizes.

Comment: You could try removing the class col-md-9 from all the div tags on click instead of just the one that you clicked.  Like this  $(".blah").removeClass("col-md-9"); instead of $(this).removeClass("col-md-9");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".blah").on('click', function () {
    $('.blah').removeClass('col-md-9').addClass('col-md-1');
    $(this).addClass('col-md-9'); 
});
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xu8p/10/)

Hope this helps..

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements of the question "Unless I click on the larger column, which would then set them all back to equal sizes."

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$(".blah").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('col-md-9')) {//if large
        $(this).removeClass('col-md-9').addClass('col-md-3')//remove 9 add 3
        .siblings('.col').removeClass('col-md-1 col-md-9').addClass('col-md-3');//remove 1,9 add 3
    } else {//if not large
        $(this).removeClass('col-md-1 col-md-3').addClass('col-md-9')//remove 1,3 add 9
        .siblings('.col').removeClass('col-md-3 col-md-9').addClass('col-md-1');//remove 3,9 add 1
    }
});
```

`.toggleClass()` can be fickle, make sure you use `.removeClass()` in the instances that you never want element(s) to have a particular class, and use `addClass()` where it should always get a particular class added.

I wrapped this in an `if` statement since here are more than 2 classes being moved around, and a particular clicked element can have a current class of any of the options.

I also added a class of `.col` on the columns which adds `float:left` to them so they nest inline.

**[Made A Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/2yxSZ/)**

This can also be done inline, without a grid framework: [**like this...**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/h4HLR/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `.toggleClass()` fickle?

Comment: nothing fickle about toggleClass... you can always pass in second argument

Comment: When using it with multiple classes in an `or` scenario, where it can only have one of the classes at a time, you have to be careful that you're only applying one class at a time and that you're not using toggle in an instance where you never want that class to be applied; it should be removed explicitly instead.